# How to check (during runtime) if the user included a file

Tags: c++, input, keyboard, include, sdl

I'm writing a small library in SDL for game programing. The library takes care of the game-loop, keyboard and mouse input. I have separated the library in 3 small files:

- ./gamelibrary.h
- ./Input/Keyboard.h
- ./Input/Mouse.h

Now, in the main game loop, I check for the SDL_Quit event (so I can provide a window that can be closed by default), and also Keyboard and Mouse events. The Keyboard and Mouse classes are static classes that can be accessed anytime to get a Keyboard/Mouse state (just like XNA). I wrote the Keyboard class as follows:

```
#ifndef KEYBOARD_INPUT
#define KEYBOARD_INPUT

#include <set>

namespace DGL
{
    struct KeyboardState {
        std::set<Uint8> keys;
        bool isKeyDown(Uint8 key)
        {
            return keys.find(key) != keys.end();
        }
        bool isKeyUp(Uint8 key)
        {
            return !isKeyDown(key);
        }
    };
    class Keyboard {
        /**
         * This class handles keyboard input game-like
         */
    private:
        static std::queue<SDL_Event> events;
    public:
        void insertEvent(SDL_Event event)
        {
            events.push(event);
        }
        void eraseEvents()
        {
            std::queue<SDL_Event> empty;
            swap(events, empty);
        }
        static KeyboardState getKeyBoardState()
        {
            KeyboardState state;
            while ( !Keyboard::events.empty() )
            {
                SDL_Event event = events.front();
                Keyboard::events.pop();
                state.keys.insert(event.key.keysym.sym);
            }
            return state;
        }
    };
    std::queue<SDL_Event> Keyboard::events;
}

#endif
```

As you can see, the user can use the method `Keyboard::getKeyboardState()` to get a struct with the current state of the keyboard. Like so:

```
...
...
KeyboardState state = Keyboard::getKeyboardState()
if ( state.isKeyDown(SDLK_w) )
{
    ....
}
....
```

The struct gets populated using the events in the 'events' static std::queue, which receives its values from the game-loop, when the event is not SDL_Quit but SDL_KEYDOWN.

I want to find a way to call `Keyboard::insertEvent()` (from the gameloop) ONLY if the user included the library itself (Keyboard.h).

As you can see, I tried to solve my problem using include-guards, but it doesn't work during runtime.

I hope I explained my problem correctly. Best regards.

Comment: What do you mean with *only if the user has included the library itself*? In one translation unit? In all translation units? Before some other include file when the latter is included?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I have a static class for both the keyboard and mouse, and the main loop saves the state of pressed keys and buttons to each corresponding class. I want my main loop, to only do this, if the user includes the Keyboard and Mouse files, because that means the user will want to read input. P.S. I want this to work even if the user includes the Keyboard and Mouse files after the main loop file, include guards only work if the user includes the files before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include guard is the key:

```
#ifdef KEYBOARD_INPUT
DGL::Keyboard kbd;
#endif

...

#ifdef KEYBOARD_INPUT
kbd.insertEvent(...);
#endif
```

Comment: Yeah, but I think this only works if the user includes the `Keyboard.h` file before this code right?

Comment: Yes, which was the whole point of your question: "I want to find a way to call Keyboard::insertEvent() (from the gameloop) **ONLY if the user included the library itself (Keyboard.h).**".  If the user includes `keyboard.h`, then you can use the `Keyboard` class, otherwise you can ignore it.